# Traverse an array in least amount of hops, online coding challenge for tech company interview

Tags: arrays, shortest-path, dijkstra

I did an interview question/coding challenge where I needed to come up with the shortest amount of "hops" through an array "arr" where at each index i could jump 1->arr[i].

One twist is that I cannot land on any indexes with a 0 as its value.

When I started to work out the problem I started thing of the array as a directed graph where each index was a node i and their children were represented by all reachable nodes i+1->i+arr[i].

When you imagine this as a graph I thought that using Dijkstra's was a good approach as then I wouldn't need to iterate over the array a million times to find the best path.

This was not an adequate answer accordign to the engineer, is my thinking off? Or did i just not execute in my implementation.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */

        // get canyon from standard in
        Integer[] canyon = getInput();

        // This problem is a twist on the shortest path algorithm (Dijkstras), the array is like a graph
        // with the values being used to determine the "edges" to different "nodes" aka other indexes with
        // non zero values

        // these are used for tracking the necessary details of our "graph"
        // we could have make an actual graph or made an array of objects with these fields but given
        // the potential size of the input, 3 arrays made most sense

        // the current ammount of jumps to reach this space, set to int max for starters
        int[] cost = getIntArray(canyon.length, true);

        // tracking if the "nodes" are yet "known"/"discovered" by the algorithm
        // dragon nodes are set to known so the algorithm will ignore them
        boolean[] known = getBoolArray(canyon, canyon.length);

        // used to point back ward to the previos step in the shorts path to each node
        // can be traversed backwards from destination to get shortest path from root
        int[] path = getIntArray(canyon.length, false);

        // starting at the beginning, we are assuming the starting place cannot be null
        if (canyon[0] == 0){
            System.out.println("failure");
            return;
        }

        // start by adding the root to "known" paths
        int root = 0;
        cost[root] = 0;
        known[root] = true;
        // do not need to calculate path to root

        //now the traverse the canyon, how far can we jump at first?
        int maxJump = canyon[root];

        //lets find every node we can jump to that's not a dragon
        for(int jump = 1; jump <= maxJump; jump++){
            int leap;

            //we need to handle the case of jumping beyond the canyon, which should map to a sngle "node"
            //this is handled in our cost, path, and known arrays
            if (root + jump >= canyon.length){
                leap = canyon.length;
            } else {
                leap = root + jump;
            }

            if (!known[leap]){
                // we can jump here! lets set the cost and path to reachable nodes

                //our "so far" best path to this node has gone up by one jump
                //including root here to show that's its a jump from root
                cost[leap]++;
                path[leap] = root;
            }

            // we've already passed the end of the canyon, we're done
            if(leap == canyon.length)
                break;
        }

        // now we traverse the canyon until we've discovered every node, and know its shortest path
        // one invariant of the algorithm is that once you "know" a node, you know (one of) its shortest paths
        while (remainingUnknownNodes(known)){

            //find the node with the lowest cost
            int minNextNode = getUnknownNodeWithLowestCost(known, cost);

            if (minNextNode == -1){
                // this means we couldn't find a next place to jump that wasn't a dragon
                // we're doomed!
                System.out.println("failure");
                return;
            }

            known[minNextNode] = true;

            // check if we just discovered the shortest path out
            if (minNextNode == canyon.length)
                break;

            // still searching, lets check where we can jump and see if we can update their paths
            maxJump = canyon[minNextNode];
            for(int jump = 1; jump <= maxJump; jump++){
                int leap;
                if (minNextNode + jump >= canyon.length){
                    leap = canyon.length;
                } else {
                    leap = minNextNode + jump;
                }
                if (!known[leap]){
                    int costNow = cost[leap];
                    int costNew = cost[minNextNode] + 1;

                    if (costNew < costNow){
                        cost[leap]++;
                        path[leap] = minNextNode;
                    }
                }

                // we've already passed the end of the canyon, we're done
                if(leap == canyon.length)
                    break;
            }
        }

        // lets print out our path of "nodes"
        System.out.println(printPath(path, path.length - 1));
    }

    // returns an array of ints used for tracking current paths and costs of each node
    // depending on the context
    private static int[] getIntArray(int length, boolean isCostArray){
        int[] arr = new int[length + 1]; // extra index to represent beyond the canyon
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            if(isCostArray){
                arr[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            } else {
                // path array
                arr[i] = -1;
            }
        }
        if(isCostArray){
            arr[length] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        } else {
            // path array
            arr[length] = -1;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    // returns a boolean array used for tracing which nodes are "known" to the algorithm
    private static boolean[] getBoolArray(Integer[] canyon, int length){
        boolean[] arr = new boolean[length + 1]; // extra index to represent beyond the canyon
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            if(canyon[i] == 0){
                // this spot has a dragon so we don't want to include it in our search
                // so we'll just say we "know" it
                arr[i] = true;
            } else {
                arr[i] = false;
            }
        }
        arr[length] = false;
        return arr;
    }

    // helper method to see if there are any remaining nodes that are unknown
    private static boolean remainingUnknownNodes(boolean[] known){
        for (int i = 0; i < known.length; i ++){
            if (known[i] == false)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // helper method used to get the next node in the shortest path algorithm
    private static int getUnknownNodeWithLowestCost(boolean[] known, int[] cost){
        int minCost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        int minNode = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < known.length; i++){
            if (!known[i] && cost[i] < minCost){
                minCost = cost[i];
                minNode = i;
            }
        }
        return minNode;
    }


    // helper method that prints the path
    private static String printPath(int[] path, int index){
        if (index == 0){
            return Integer.toString(index);
        } else {
            String str = index == path.length - 1 ? "out" : Integer.toString(index);

            return printPath(path, path[index]) + ", " + str;
        }
    }

    //helper method that gets input from STDIN
    private static Integer[] getInput(){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        LinkedList<Integer> initialNumbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        while(in.hasNextInt()) {
            initialNumbers.add(in.nextInt());
        }
        Integer[] canyon = new Integer[initialNumbers.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < canyon.length; i++){
            canyon[i] = initialNumbers.get(i);
        }

        return canyon;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you signed an NDA if you took this through HackerRank... In which case you probably shouldn't be posting your solution on Stackoverflow regardless of if you passed or failed.

This solution is inefficient because you used Dijkstra's algorithm needlessly - the solution can be found without knowing the cost to every index in the array. "Work smarter, not harder" would be an appropriate adage. A problem like this can be solved in such a way that the first answer arrived at is the best.